# Compare a genome's double combination percentages with a reference genomes' percentages

Tags: r, compare, genome

I have 3 unknown genomes and I have 15 genomes(5 for bacteria,5 for fungus,5 for yeast). I found double combinations of all these genomes. Double combinations are AA,AT,AG,AC,...(16 combinations). Then,i found their percentage in the genome. Finally, i got 3 reference average percentage values from bacteria,fungus and yeast and I want to compare these percentage values with the 3 unknown genome percentages. By the way, I can define which genome belongs to which family. What should I do,is there any package to perform these ?

For example, I have test1percentages as follows;

```
>0.09583437 -- 0.05393204 -- 0.06488782 -- 0.07903921 -- 0.06890654 -- 0.04395304 -- 0.02788807  
0.06502646 -- 0.06932366 -- 0.03773925 -- 0.04409289 -- 0.05457230 -- 0.05962886 -- 0.07014978  
0.06885963 -- 0.09616608
```

And I have bacteria,fungus,yeast percentages as;

```
>allbacs

 0.05421850 -- 0.05540724 -- 0.05065422 -- 0.05524792 -- 0.06539913 -- 
 0.07254104 -- 0.09583958 
 0.05023776 -- 0.05921741 -- 0.09700061 -- 0.07263406 -- 0.05576768 --
 0.03669278 -- 0.05906868 --
 0.06549191 -- 0.05458147

>allyeasts

0.08239379 -- 0.05602528 -- 0.05407910 -- 0.07096754 -- 0.05685478 -- 0.05165226 -- 0.04809652
0.06476042 -- 0.06680492 -- 0.04832589 -- 0.04111317 -- 0.05642334 --
0.05840699 -- 0.06536005 --
0.06937911 -- 0.10935685

>allfungus

 0.08458809 -- 0.05068602 -- 0.07291263 -- 0.07811563 -- 0.04697502 -- 
 0.05680199 -- 0.04689305 
 0.06906349 -- 0.05600454 -- 0.05504048 -- 0.04973311 -- 0.05383871 --
 0.09893712 -- 0.05720541 
 0.04476084 -- 0.07844389
```

(Test1 belongs to fungus)

How can I compare their similarity ? I tried to plot and comment on them, but professor said it should be automatic.

Thanks

Comment: What is test1percentage? How do you want to compare the three bacteria, fungus, yeast? Mean?

Comment: Test1percentage is the genome of first unknown organism. I want to compare each of the unknown genomes(I have 3 of them) with the reference percentage values that i measured.

Comment: OK, but compare in what way? A global mean? A paired test? Distribution?

Comment: Also I am asking this question,but a friend helped me. He referred me to calculate distances between references. I couldn't get the exact values(because yeast and fungus values are closer). I distinguished bacteria from others but I am still looking for another method to calculate between fungus and yeast.

Comment: You are not answering my question... but since you mentioned distances, this could be done using hierarchical clustering.

Comment: Calculating the distances couldn't solve the problem correctly. Then, I used to calculate z point for each of the test sample vs. reference values; I got the right answer.